# Value of $\frac{3n^2 + 3n - 1}{5} \mod m$

Tags: number-theory

I am writing a program to solve a problem and but unable to figure out which property to use.
Given some value $n \leq 10^{10}$ , and some  $m \leq 10^{5}$.
Have to find the value of $$\frac{3n^2 + 3n - 1}{5} \mod m$$
But there are few constraints,

- I cannot directly evaluate $n^2$ as it will overflow $64\ bit$ range of my program in worst case.
- But in the given equation it it known that numerator is perfectly divisible by $5$, *i.e* ${(3n^2 + 3n - 1)}\equiv 0\pmod 5$.

Though i can add and subtract without overflowing the bound, and even multiply it with numbers as long as result is under $64 \ bit$ range.
I am unable to figure out what property to use so get the solution, without manually implementing multiplication and division using characters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm guessing that the reason you have $m \le 10^5$ is exactly so that you can work out $n \pmod m$ before squaring it - i.e. $n^2 \pmod m \equiv (n \mod m) (n \mod m)$

Comment: Don't mix $m$ and $M$. That's very confusing. Pick one.

Comment: @Mathmo123 yes you are right, but there is 5 in division, so i cannot directly take mod and then divide, as 5 it need not to be coprime with M

Comment: Figuring out $(3n^2+3n-1)/5 \pmod m$ is equivalent to figuring out $3n^2+3n-1 \pmod{5m}$. Also, fwiw, $n\equiv3\pmod5$ also makes $3n^2+3n-1$ divisible by $5$.

Comment: @GregMartin I have an idea, what if i take a prime $p$ which is coprime with 5 and then take mod in numerator first and then multiply the result with {5^-1}mod p. It will restore the result also and i'll get things within bounds..

Comment: If you want to solve the equation - so write the equation. This notation is confusing, what should be sought is not clear.  If the number is $n=5k+1$ ; $n=5k-2$ always divisible by 5.